# Node.js – Create server

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js - I tried to create server with node and test if it's running, but the terminal doesn't print me out: Server is listening on port 3000.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh63L.png)

This is the code that I have written:

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()

const port=process.env.port || 3000

app.listen(port)
console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: Does he print anything at all? A error message or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install express if you want to use the code. Use this command in the directory with the package.json

```
npm install express
```

The startpoint for the app is defined in the package.json as "main" : "yourScript.js"

After that you can start the code with the command

```
node yourScript.js
```

The server should start and print out your port.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `app.listen()` needs two parameters
You've provided the first which is the "port"
The second one is a callback function where you can put your `console.log()` statement

```
app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`)
}
```